# NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 3 input values to the 587028 output values where the mask is true

Tags: python, image-segmentation

I am trying to learn codes from the Youtube channel DigitalSreeni :　Histogram based image segmentation in Python

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kIVk0IhDMwY&list=PLZsOBAyNTZwbIjGnolFydAN33gyyGP7lT&index=24&ab_channel=DigitalSreeni

The code is as below:

＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝

```
from skimage.restoration import denoise_nl_means, estimate_sigma

from skimage import img_as_ubyte, img_as_float, io

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

import os
print(os.getcwd())

filename = 'C:/Users/user/'
f1 = (filename + '20220614_1.jpg')
print(f1)


img = img_as_float(io.imread(f1))

sigma_est = np.mean(estimate_sigma(img, multichannel=True))

denoise = denoise_nl_means(img, h=1.15 * sigma_est, fast_mode=True, 
                               patch_size=5, patch_distance=3, multichannel=True)
        

denoise_ubyte = img_as_ubyte(denoise)

segm1 = (denoise_ubyte <= 57)
segm2 = (denoise_ubyte > 57) & (denoise_ubyte <= 110)
segm3 = (denoise_ubyte > 110) & (denoise_ubyte <= 210)
segm4 = (denoise_ubyte > 210)


all_segments = np.zeros((denoise_ubyte.shape[0], denoise_ubyte.shape[1], 3)) 

all_segments[segm1] = (1,0,0)
all_segments[segm2] = (0,1,0)
all_segments[segm3] = (0,0,1)
all_segments[segm4] = (1,1,0)

plt.imshow(all_segments)
```

＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝

I tried to run the code basically without many changes but there is an error alert:

```
ValueError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 3 input values to the 587028 output values where the mask is true
```

May I know the reasons? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

for me I tried

```
img2 = cv2.imread("images/BSE_Google_noisy.jpg")
img = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

and its worked
and also I change `multichannel=True` to `channel_axis=None`